# How to make a Spotfire link open faster?

Tags: performance, database-performance, spotfire

I've published a Spotfire file with 70 '.txt' files linked to it. The total size of the files is around 2Gb. when the users open it in their web browser it takes + - 27 minutes to load the linked tables.

I need an option that enhances opening performance. The issue seems to be the aumont of data and the way they are linked to Spotfire.

This runs in a server and the users open the BI in their browser.

I've tryed to embeed the data, it lowers the time, but forces me to interact with the software every time I want to update the data. The solution is supposed to run automatically.

I need to open this in less than 5 minutes.

Update: 
- I need the data to be updated at least twice a day.
- The embedded link is acceptable from the time perspective, but the system need to run without my intetrvention.
- I've never used Spotfire automation services.

Comment: I've edited the question, tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule the report to cache twice a day on the Spotfire server by setting up a rule under scheduling and routing. The good thing about this is while it is updating the analysis for the second time during the day, it will still allow users to quickly open older data until it is complete. To the end user it will open in seconds but behind the scenes you have just pre-opened the report. Once you set up the rule this will run automatically with no intervention needed.

All functionality and scripting within the report will work the same, and it can be opened up many times at the same time from different users. This is really the best way if you have to link to that many files. Otherwise, try collapsing files, aggregating data, removing all unnecessary columns and data tables for the data to pull through faster.